# Or operator in if statement not working as intended

Tags: excel, vba, divide-by-zero

When I use the following code it works fine:

```
If xMin <> 0 Then
    If xMax <> 0 Then
        If xMax / xMin > 2 Then
            'some code
        End If
    End If
End If
```

But I want to use only one if statement to avoid division errors,    however it gives me a `Run-time error '11': Division by zero`:

```
If xMin <> 0 Or xMax <> 0 Then
    If xMax / xMin > 2 Then
        'some code
    End If
End If
```

(If I can manage to make the above code work), I plan to do it like:

```
If (xMin <> 0 Or xMax <> 0) And (xMax / xMin > 2) Then
    'some code
End If
```

What is the reason behind this and how can I make it work in one if statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're out of luck.

VBA does not implement a *short-circuited* `And`, unlike C, C++, Java, &c. It evaluates every term in the expression even if the result is already known. In your case that means that `xMax / xMin` is evaluated even if `xMin` is 0.

So you need to write it as

```
If xMin <> 0 And xMax <> 0 Then
    If xMax / xMin > 2 Then
        'some code
    End If
End If
```

Note that I've fixed a typo in your conditional: you need an `And` in place of your `Or`.

Comment: Well, using `If xMin <> 0 Or xMax <> 0 Then` gives me an error as I stated in my question. Only the first code in my question is working properly.

Comment: Yes I've just noticed that and have amended the answer. Note you need `And`, not `Or`.

Comment: But if I use `And`, it executes the inner if statement: i.e.: `xMax = 350`, `xMin = 0` which pops a division error.

Comment: It works without any error as you said, and it is beyond my understanding. Either VBA is a joke, or not capable of simple logical operations. I will accept your answer, thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just check the value of `xMin`?  If `xMax` is 0 the calculation will return 0.  It'll only return an error if `xMin` is 0.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: Indeed to obviate a division by zero, that's all you need to do. But I preserve the conditions where `'some code` will run.

Comment: Yes, that bit still needs checking but I was thinking along the lines of: check if xMin <> 0, if it is then check the result of xMax/xMin > 2.